# AddView to ListView not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, view, xamarin

I have a Loading Overlay that I am using through out my app.
The way I have it setup right now is:

```
var inflater = Application.Context.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
var loadingOverlayView = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.LoadingOverlay, null);

Dialog loadingOverlayDialog = new Dialog (context, Resource.Style.loadingOverlayFadeInAndOut);
loadingOverlayDialog.RequestWindowFeature ((int)WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
loadingOverlayDialog.SetContentView (loadingOverlayView);
```

This way, this `Dialog` that has the `loadingOverlayView`, takes up my entire screen.
I want to change it.

I tried to add the `loadingOverlayView` to the `ListView` that is on my `Activity`.
But I get the following error:

`addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView`

So how can I make my overlay view cover only part of my screen?
I only want it to cover the `ListView` so user can still use other functionality on the activity.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: put your listview in a framelayout, and add your overlay to the framelayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the ListView inside a RelativeLayout and then add the overlay to the layout.

Comment: DUH! I feel kinda stupid lol. Thank you! but i do have another problem.  When this was covering the whole screen, overlay was automatic because i was using a Dialog.  How can I get an overlay for this view? All I see now is my image in the center.

Comment: You could either try if the FrameLayout njzk2 suggested would do this automatically or if you need to set the bounds of the layout AND call BringToFront(...) followed by Invalidate(...).

Comment: So I set the view's `LayoutParams` to fit `RelativeLayout` but BringToFront() and Invalidate() did not work.  I set the View's background from resource, which was an XML color.  I created colors.xml in my Resources/values and created a custom color.  `<color name="overlayColor">#30000000</color>` .  The color is black (#000000) with 30 in front of it. 30 is the alpha (opacity) of the color.  I found out, you can do that with any color.